# How to initialize a bash array with output piped from another command?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any way to pipe the output of a command which lists a bunch of numbers (each number in a separate line) and initialize a bash array with those numbers?

Details: 
This lists 3 changelist numbers which have been submitted in the following date range. The output is then piped to `cut` to filter it further to get just the changelist numbers.

```
p4 changes -m 3 -u edk -s submitted @2009/05/01,@now | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

E.g. :

```
422311
543210
444000
```

How is it possible to store this list in a bash array?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can execute the command under ticks and set the Array like,

```
ARRAY=(`command`)
```

Alternatively, you can save the output of the command to a file and cat it similarly,

```
command > file.txt
ARRAY=(`cat file.txt`)
```

Or, simply one of the following forms suggested in the comments below,

```
ARRAY=(`< file.txt`)
ARRAY=($(<file.txt))
```

Comment: Useless use of cat: `<file.txt` does the same.

Comment: fixed the answer for future reference.

Comment: Whenever possible, avoid the use of back quotes. This is more readable and can work with nesting without awkward quoting: ARRAY=($(command)) or ARRAY=($(< file.txt))

Comment: Be warned that this will ALWAYS use whitespace to separate elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449417/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-into-an-array reports possibility to handle whitespace by setting `IFS` to `'\n'` but I couldn't make it accept `'\0'`.

Comment: Why does `folders=(\`ls -1 ${FOLDER} | xargs\`)` give me `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` ?

Comment: Self-answer: because I had `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash` … :roll:

Comment: This splits the input by spaces, not by newlines.

Answer (score 16):

If you use bash 4+, it has special command for this: [mapfile](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) also known as [readarray](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray), so you can fill your array like this:

```sh
declare -a a
readarray -t a < <(command)
```

for more portable version you can use

```
declare -a a
while read i; do
  a=( "${a[@]}" "$i" )
done < <(command)
```

Comment: This is my first time seeing `< <(command)`. Can you please help me find more detail on this syntax. I'm interested in knowing why it needs 2 `<` to work. Thanks

Comment: First `<` is redirection of input stream, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Input for detains. Construction `<(command)` means that output of `command` is piped to named fifo (usually `/dev/fdn`), you can find details on it at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html.

Comment: Be warned that `readarray` doesn't support an alternative separator, it always uses newline.

Comment: `a[${#a[*]}]=value` or `a+=(value)` is a better syntax to append to an array.

Comment: Re @ivan_pozdeev `readarray`/`mapfile` apparently does support defining alternative delimiters. The [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) specify `-d delim`: "The first character of delim is used to terminate each input line, rather than newline."

Comment: @AllanLewis `-d` for `readarray` [is new in `bash 4.4`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/diff/NEWS?id=a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071).

Answer (score 3):

Quite similar to #4 but looks a bit better for me. :)

```
declare -a a
readarray -t a <<< $(command)
```

Comment: Interesting alternative. However the methods differ in case of an empty output from the command, the here-string method gives an array having one empty item, whereas the names pipe method gives an empty array.