# Read multiple variables from another variable

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a command `my_command` which I am sure outputs three lines like

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

and I want to store the three lines into three variables `$x`, `$y`, `$z`. How can I accomplish this in bash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I assign the output of a command into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449417/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-into-an-array)

Comment: I would prefer to keep the names x,y,z as they are quantities that have meaning and increase the readability of the code.

Comment: Well that's why is a _possible_ duplicate. As well, you could just alias the array values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for name in x y z; do
    read $name
done < <(my_command)
```

This uses process substitution so that the `read` commands are not executed in a subshell and the resulting variables are available after the loop completes. The variable `name` is used to hold the *names* of the variables to set; `$name` expands to the name of the variable that `read` sets, so after the loop you have three variables `x`, `y`, and `z` that hold each of the three lines of your output.

You can also use a here document instead of process substitution:

```
for name in x y z; do
    read $name
done <<EOF
$(my_command)
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

And here's another:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' x y z __ < <(my_command)
```

With `-d ''` it sets the delimiter to `'\0'` and makes `read` read the whole input in one instance, and not just a single line. `IFS=$'\n'` sets newline (`\n`) as the separator for each value. `__` is optional and gathers any extra input besides the first 3 lines.

From `help read`:

> Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor
>   FD if the -u option is supplied. The line is split into fields as with
>   word splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the
>   second word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words
>   assigned to the last NAME. Only the characters found in $IFS are
>   recognized as word delimiters.
>
> -d delim      continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather than newline