# Bash: Store Output of Command to Array with \n as delimiter

Tags: arrays, bash, delimiter

I have Output like that:

```
dn: CN=XXX XXX,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,O=XXX
cn: XXX XXX
telephonenumber: 1234

dn: CN=XXX XXX,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,O=XXX
cn: XXX XXX
telephonenumber: 1090

dn: CN=XXX XXX,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,O=XXX
cn: XXX XXX
telephonenumber: 1012
```

I get this output from a simple `ldapsearch` command.
I want to store this output in an array so that i can `echo` an index and get one ldap entry like

```
echo ${ldaparray[1]}

dn: CN=XXX XXX,OU=XXX,OU=XXX,O=XXX
cn: XXX XXX
telephonenumber: 1090
```

So I to array delimiter would be an empty new line I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assign the output of a command into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449417/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-into-an-array)

Comment: @JulienLopez looks good. But how is the IFS for an empty new line? with $='\n' he splits every new line to an index

Comment: Whoops, you're right, sorry. You may need to use awk or a loop on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to build your array, with some help from awk:

```
ldaparray=()
while IFS='' read -d '' -r record; do
    ldaparray+=( "$record" )
done < <(awk -v RS= -v ORS='\0' '1' file)
```

Setting `RS` to the empty string makes awk treat each block of text as a separate record. `1` is always true, so each record is printed, separated by the `ORS`, a null byte.

The loop reads each of these records and adds a value to the array.

Change `<(awk ... file)` to `<(command | awk ...)`, if you want to work with the output of a command, rather than the contents of a file.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to store it in an array but can use the below script to get the i'th entry.

Usage:

```
./print_index.sh filename index
```

Example, to print the second entry from file sample.txt use

```
 
./print_index.sh sample.txt 2
```

FILE=$1
INDEX=$2

LINE_NUMBER=`cat $FILE| grep -n "telephonenumber"| awk -F':' {'print $1'}| head -$INDEX| tail -1`

head -$LINE_NUMBER $FILE| tail -3

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your array by iterating on the lines, for example:

```
# Current index of the array
i=0

# For every line of input (so ignoring '\n's)
while read line; do
    # If the line is empty, then we write in the next array spot
    if test "$line" = ""; then
        i=$(($i+1))
        continue
    fi
    # If this spot already contains some lines,
    # then we concatenate a '\n' then our current line to the array spot
    if test "${ldaparray[$i]}" != ""; then
        ldaparray[$i]="${ldaparray[$i]}\n$line"
    # else no need for a '\n'
    else
        ldaparray[$i]="$line"
    fi
done < <(ldapsearch ...)
```

Comment: How do I actually read the output of the command? like do I need to put a `cat ldapsearch .... `before your script !?

Comment: @JMAD2016 The command is in the last line: `done < <(ldapsearch ...)`.