# How to store the output from "ansible-vault encrypt_string" into a varibale in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to use the following ansible-vault command in a **bash script** and store its output into an array:

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-password-file ./password "string" --name 'encrypted_val' | values[i++]
```

If I have the following command on its own, it prints the encrypted value:

```
encrypted_val: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          63626631313232396664393364363435363939323966623163343463326630613632626336363361
          3837356365373434353331386563656162316338613036360a393362646661633136326537646230
          65386331613833336565653062616237653831333763616332346364633536306539303839313061
          3230633261396138650a343465316332666636373436366136313337303238613365363365343931
          3662
Encryption successful
```

I want to store this output in an array. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426529/reading-output-of-a-command-into-an-array-in-bash or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449417/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-into-an-array

Comment: Thank you!! @miken32