# Substring from a output of a command

Tags: bash, shell

Execute the below command and got the output-
command=

```
keytool -list -keystore /etc/pki/java/cacerts -storepass "changeit" | grep _abc_
```

output=

```
_abc_sec1, Mar 23, 2021, trustedCertEntry,
_abc_sec2, Aug 30, 2021, trustedCertEntry,
```

What is the easiest and short way to fetch  `_abc_sec1`  and `_abc_sec2` one by one and store in a variable

Comment: `keytool ... | grep -o '_abc_sec[12]'` , the `o` being a GNU extension.

Comment: What to you mean by "one by one..."? Storing into an array, concatenate it into a string, or making a loop for using the current value into a variable to be used within the loop?

Comment: @Mike : What do you mean by _store in a variable_ : Do you want both strings to occur in the same variable (if yes, how should they be separated), or do you want them to end up in an array holding 2 elements?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) to get the first column (separated by `,`)

We can use the `arr=( $(command) )` syntax to parse the output to a bash array.
<sup>[How do I assign the output of a command into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449417/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-into-an-array)</sup>

Then we can easily loop over each substring:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

arr=( $(keytool -list -keystore /etc/pki/java/cacerts -storepass "changeit" | grep _abc_ | cut -d',' -f1) )

for ss in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "--> $ss"
done
```

---

Local example, we're I've placed the 'input' in a text file to mimic the command:

```
$ cat input
_abc_sec1, Mar 23, 2021, trustedCertEntry,
_abc_sec2, Aug 30, 2021, trustedCertEntry,
something else
$
$
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash

arr=( $(cat input| grep _abc_ | cut -d',' -f1) )

for ss in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "--> $ss"
done
$
$
$ ./tst.sh
--> _abc_sec1
--> _abc_sec2
$
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine , what is this -f1 used for ?

Comment: The `-f1` means: get field number 1. So after splitting on each `,`, we only want the first Field